# Why not fail silently when a user attempts to re-upvote a comment?

Tags: feature-request, error-message

This is a really little thing, but it bugs me every time it happens. Steps to reproduce:

1. Upvote comment
2. Navigate to another page
3. Use browser's back button to return to page you commented on
4. Observe your upvote is no longer shown
5. Think to yourself, "Silly Stack Overflow. My vote must not have registered."
6. Attempt to upvote the comment again

At this point, since you've already voted on the comment, and the vote was indeed registered, Stack Overflow displays this beauty letting you know just how forgetful you are:

[image: "You cannot mark a comment more than once" message]

But why?

I don't see any reason Stack Overflow couldn't just say, "OK, got it" and just update the interface to show your vote.

In my opinion, this error serves no purpose.

Comment: It does serve a purpose. Otherwise you'd have a clickable element which wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @yivi That's not what I'm proposing. I'm proposing clicking upvote on a comment you already upvoted simply display the upvote, in essence saying, "Yup, you voted," just as it does every other time you upvote a comment. So it would do something.

Answer (score 9):

Sure it does: it affirms to the user that their vote was indeed registered.

Further, I suspect many-to-most users of this particular platform will then intuit "Oh, my cache is to blame because I navigated" and never worry about it again.

Failing silently, on the other hand, would lead me to believe that my original vote *was not registered*, thereby reducing my overall confidence in the system.

A large part of the point of Stack Exchange is voting. If users don't have absolute confidence that pressing that up/down button will record their vote, people will be even less likely to bother voting than they already are. That sounds like a snide remark, but you've [only to look at the views / votes ratio of many questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/821578)<sup>§</sup> to see what I mean.

<sup>§</sup> Yes, that infers votes from score, but `VoteCount` is not an available feature and I think it's a fair approximation.

Comment: Not sure I entirely agree, but a fair argument.

Comment: A large part of the point of Stack Exchange is voting. If users don't have absolute confidence that when pressing that button will record their vote, people will be even less likely to bother voting than they already are. (That sounds like a snide remark, but you've only to look at the views / votes ratio of many questions to see what I mean.)